# Why is my custom accessory button not changing image when tapped (ios)?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitableview

I'm trying to make an accessory view similar to  [Apple's demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Accessory/Listings/MyTableViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008066-MyTableViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6), but i must have missed something because mine doesn't switch the image when clicked. It just
[flickers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZA1HeRRZT4&feature=youtu.be).

Not sure what i missed, i tried to base it exactly off the demo code.
I had to change a couple of dictionaries to mutable and add an if cell null clause to make mine work though.
The items are fetched and displayed properly in the tableview.
I've emboldened the parts that i changed, i think i got them all.
Any help much appreciated thanks.

My code:
Header declaration:

```
@interface PollQueryController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

.m file:

```
    @interface PollQueryController ()

        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;

    @end

    @implementation PollQueryController


    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization

        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        [super viewDidLoad];

    //    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pollData" ofType:@"plist"];
    //    NSDictionary *pollsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pollData" ofType:@"plist"]];
        
        NSArray * pollsData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pollData" ofType:@"plist"]];
        NSMutableArray * choices = [[[pollsData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"choices"] mutableCopy]; // mutable

    //    NSMutableArray *choices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:choicesArray]; // Mutable

        self.dataArray = choices;

        NSLog(@"array: %@", self.dataArray);

    // swipe gestures
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer * Swiperight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiperight:)];
        Swiperight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:Swiperight];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer * Swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
        Swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:Swipeleft];

        self.title = @"Poll Query";

        self.feedTableView.dataSource = self;
        self.feedTableView.delegate = self;

        self.feedTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.feedTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:0.6];


        UIColor* mainColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255 green:102.0/255 blue:147.0/255 alpha:1.0f];

        NSString* fontName = @"Optima-Italic";
        NSString* boldFontName = @"Optima-ExtraBlack";

        UIFont* socialFont = [UIFont fontWithName:boldFontName size:10.0f];
        UIColor* socialColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    }



    #pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return self.dataArray.count;
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellID";

        FeedCell3* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];

    // i had to add this, whereas the demo doesnt do this.

           if (cell == nil) {
               cell = [[FeedCell3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"feedcell3"];
           }


        NSMutableDictionary *item = [[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy];   // mutable
        cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];


        [item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];

        BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

        UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"ticked24"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unticked24"];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        button.frame = frame;
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.accessoryView = button;

        UIColor* blueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:47.0/255 green:168.0/255 blue:228.0/255 alpha:1.0f];


        cell.textLabel.textColor = blueColor;
        NSString* fontName = @"Optima-Italic";
        NSString* boldFontName = @"Optima-ExtraBlack";
        UIFont* socialFont = [UIFont fontWithName:boldFontName size:10.0f];
        cell.textLabel.font = socialFont;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;


        return cell;
    }


    #pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate


    - (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
    {
        NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.feedTableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.feedTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

        if (indexPath != nil)
        {
            [self tableView: self.feedTableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
        }
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *item = [[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy] ; // mutable

        BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

        [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;

        UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unticked24"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"ticked24"];
        [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        [self tableView: self.feedTableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
        [self.feedTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }



    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    -(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
    {

        if(_hasVoted){

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"QueryToResults" sender: self];
        }

    }

    -(void)swiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"friendsBackToPollSeg" sender: self];

    }



    @end
```

Comment: The reason you had to add the code where the `cell == nil` is because you forgot to call either `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` on your UITableView.

Comment: I tried adding `[self.feedTableView registerClass:[FeedCell3 class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"feedcell3"];` with the prototype cell's reuse identifier set to `feedcell3` in storyboard but it didnt help. I still need the `cell==nil` otherwise the thread dies at `[item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow. I found why it wasnt working for me without using the mutableCopy's.
The original array was not mutable
`NSArray * pollsData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pollData" ofType:@"plist"]];`
Changing to mutable fixed the issue.
`NSMutableArray * pollsData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pollData" ofType:@"plist"]];`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that by using `mutableCopy`, you instantiate a new object each time. Thus, in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {` call, the checked value of item is always false.
I assume there is some kind of tableview reloadData at some point too. Therefore, it sets the accessoryView to the checked image, than reload it, and resets it to the unchecked value because the change to your dataArray item is not persisted (as it is applied to a copy of the object).

Long story short, the item in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` are **not** the same.

edit :

```
@interface PollQueryController () {
    NSMutableDictionary * _checkStates;
}
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
@end

@implementation PollQueryController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray * pollsData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pollData" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSMutableArray * choices = [[[pollsData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"choices"] mutableCopy]; // mutable
    self.dataArray = choices;
    _checkStates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"array: %@", self.dataArray);

    […]
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellID";

    FeedCell3* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
// i had to add this, whereas the demo doesnt do this.
       if (cell == nil) {
           cell = [[FeedCell3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"feedcell3"];
       }

    NSDictionary * item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];

    NSNumber checkedState = [_checkStates objectForKey:@"item"];
    BOOL checked = checkedState ? [checkedState boolValue] : NO;

    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"ticked24"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unticked24"];

    […]

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSNumber checkedState = [_checkStates objectForKey:item];
    BOOL checked = checkedState ? YES : ![checkedState boolValue];
    [_checkStates setObject:@(checked) forKey:item];

    // You don't have a reference to the cell here anymore to update the cell accessoryView, but I believe it would be simpler to reload the cell (or the tableView)
    // I'll go with the tableview there for the sake of simplicity, but feel free to update this
    [tableView reloadData];
}
@end
```

Comment: i cant seem to get it to work without using the mutable copy's. it sigabrt's at `[item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];`

Comment: You could keep another structure (I would go with a NSMutableDictionary) alongside dataArray that would store the checkedState of your cells. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `mutableCopy` ie `NSMutableDictionary *item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` then try relaoding the cell after changing the `checked` value in accessory button tap, use

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

method to update the cell,

change `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

    [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: At breakpoint `[item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];` i get `Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION code = EXCI386_INVOP`

Comment: Why you need to add cell to `item` dictionary( `[item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];`)

Comment: This will not work since you are using `[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy];`

Comment: I tried this method with all mutableCopy's taken out and it didnt work.

Comment: Did you tried with `NSMutableDictionary *item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in accessory tap also..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45218/discussion-between-akhilrajtr-and-jsky)